# How to get http request/response bodies in Kong api gateway's http-log plugin with documented config.custom_fields_by_lua option?

Tags: logging, http, api, lua, kong

**Disclaimer**

This is well discussed topic, but it seems that the solution is not there yet.
This one seem to be an outdated duplicate, don't judge me for that.
https://discuss.konghq.com/t/logging-request-body-response-body-with-http-log/1205
The `config.custom_fields_by_lua` is not discussed there anyways.
There are also some hacky and outdated workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72337619/kong-gateway-request-and-response-body

**The question**

When I add this to the `kong.yml` no log is being generated, not just the body is not being added, but all the log message which is there otherwise, disappears when the `custom_fields_by_lua: {"body": "return kong.request.get_body()` is added.

```
plugins:
  - name: http-log
    service: mirror-service
    config:
      http_endpoint: http://localhost:8080
      method: POST
      timeout: 1000
      keepalive: 1000
      flush_timeout: 2
      retry_count: 2
      custom_fields_by_lua: {"body": "return kong.request.get_body()"
```

Comment: I figured out that it fires the following error message when get_body added to the declarative configuration.
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/pdk/private/phases.lua:102: function cannot be called in log phase (only in: rewrite, access, response, error, admin_api)

Answer (score -1):

It is not interesting for the Kong team to make this feature available:
https://github.com/Kong/kong/pull/5968#issuecomment-758871605

You can customize the http-log plugin itself or add a new plugin like:
https://github.com/zenvia/kong-plugin-http-log-with-body

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your points are already in the links provided in the question.